# How to delete user with db_owner rights?

Tags: sql-server, security

Is there an easy way to delete a user with db_owner rights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a subtle distinction between being the dbo of a database and having db_owner rights.

Have you tried setting another user as the dbo of the database (see [sp_changedbowner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259622%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)), then removing the original owner's rights before deleting?

Comment: Ahhh knew there was something I was missing. Just changed the db_owner back to original user and then deleted test user.